# Python find duplicates which occur more than 3 times

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find an efficient way to **search three or more consecutive duplicates** and replace them for only one in a Python list.

```
list_before = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]

# expected
list_after = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]

def replace(list_to_replace):
    for idx, val in enumerate(list_to_replace):
        if idx + 3 < len(list_to_replace):
            if val == list_to_replace[idx+1] == list_to_replace[idx+2]:
                del list_to_replace[idx+1]
                del list_to_replace[idx+2]
    return list_to_replace

>>> replace(list_before)
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

What seems to be the problem here? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Two problems: modifying the list as you iterate it, and performing O(n) del operation in the middle of the list. Both would be solved by appending to a new list (as is done by the groupby answer) see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I good use case for `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> list_before = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
>>> list_after = []
>>> for k, group in groupby(list_before):
...     lst = list(group)
...     if len(lst) >= 3:
...         list_after.append(k)
...     else:
...         list_after.extend(lst)
>>> list_after
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]
```

It would be possible make a one-liner with `itertools.chain` but the `for` loop is almost certainly more readable and similarly performant.

Comment: I'd much rather use yours than go for the one-liner, which not only has to deal with the quirks of consuming generators/iterators, it also has to deal with `chain`'s apparent hatred of non-iterables, lol.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> nums = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
>>> [k for k, g in groupby(nums) for i in range(1 + (len(list(g)) == 2))] 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Real smart consumption of the generator there! A well deserved +1. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Chris in his answer, a one-liner is possible but it's not pretty at all.

```
In [88]: list(chain.from_iterable([(x,) if len(y) >= 3 else y for x, y in [(k, tuple(g)) for k, g in groupby(list_before)]]))
Out[88]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]
```

I think there should be a better way but `chain` is hacky enough to deal with when dealing with non-iterables.

Comment: this ;) `list(chain.from_iterable([k]*(sum(1for _ in islice(g,3))%2 or 2) for k, g in groupby(list_before)))`

Comment: `list(chain.from_iterable([k]*(len(list(g)[:3])%2 or 2) for k, g in groupby(list_before)))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Ack, one-liners are the bane of programming sometimes. Lol

Comment: @jamylak Lol, nice oneliner! Seems like we should go to code golf now! :D

Comment: Thanks, yes when i was making it i thought how it could be shorter if itt were `range(-1, len(list(g)) == 2)` but it seemeed less readable. Even though it's already pushing it.  @Chris_Rands solution is probably the way to go for clarity, mine is a bit too cunning.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an object oriented approach, that I used on streams :

```
class StreamCount:
    def __init__(self, input_values):
        self.input_values = input_values
        self.output = []
        self.current_value = next(iter(input_values), None) # first element if there is any
        self.current_count = 0

    def process_new(self, value):
        if value == self.current_value:
            self.current_count += 1

        else:
            self.update_output()
            self.current_count = 1
            self.current_value = value

    def process_all(self):
        for v in self.input_values:
            self.process_new(v)

        # handle last values suite
        self.update_output()

        return self.output

    def update_output(self):
        if self.current_count > 2:
            self.output.append(self.current_value)
        else:
            self.output += [self.current_value for _ in range(self.current_count)]
```

**Tests**

```
input_values = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
StreamCount(input_values).process_all()
```

> ouput: 
>   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]

```
input_values = []
```

> ouput: 
>   []

```
input_values = [None]
```

> ouput: 
>   [None]

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, defining a custom method to slice the array based on condition:

```
def take_max_three(iterable):
  iterable = sorted(iterable) # It requires the iterable to be sorted, remove if already sorted
  i, x, size = 0, 0, len(iterable)
  while i < size-1:
    if iterable[i] < iterable[i+1]:
      ready = iterable[x:i+1]
      if len(ready) <= 3:
        yield ready
      else:
        yield ready[0:3]
      x = i + 1
    i += 1
  yield iterable[x:x+3]
```

Then just call the method on the array, this is a slight modified array:

```
array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 3, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9]
take_max_three(array)
# => [[1, 1, 1], [2], [3, 3], [4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8], [9]]
```

You could further customise the method passing the number of elements to take.

Answer (score -2):

This is my solution:

```
list_before = [1, 5, 7, 8, 6, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 8, 8, 5, 2, 3, 7, 8, 8]

list_after = []
for item in list_before:
    if not item in list_after:
        list_after.append(item)
```

Comment: how does this control the 3-time-occurrence of an item?

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: Using the input from the question, this gives `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` and not `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]`